# Analytic multi-roots of Weierstrass polynomial with several variables

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, analytic-functions, several-complex-variables

Let $f(w,z)=z^n+a_1(w)z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n(w)$ be a Weierstrass-polynomial of degree $n$ in $\lambda$,  whose coefficients are all analytic functions of $w\in\mathbb C^l$. Suppose that $z=z_0$ is a  root with multiplicity $m$ of $f(w_0,z)=0$.

**Q** Can we say that  for $w$ near $w_0$, there are exactly  $m$ roots $z(w)$ of $f(w,z)$ near $z_0$, and these roots $z(w)$ are the branches of one or more
   multivalued analytic functions with at worst algebraic branch points at $z=z_0$?

Comment: $f(w,z) = \prod_j (z-Z_j(w))$ then $Z_j$ is analytic at least away from the hypersurface where the discriminant $Disc(f)(w)$ (a polynomial in the $a_m(w)$) vanishes